# Disconnect connected translations in backend

Tags: typo3, translation

I have translated pages in "connected" mode. Is there any functionality to switch the content elements of existing pages  to "copied - disconnected" mode so we can add content elements individually to each translation. Previously on 6.2 LTS this was always possible. When doing the update to 8.7 LTS all pages with similar translations became automatically connected. So ideally we can do that easy for a large number of pages or disable the connected mode at all. It would not help to disable translate vie Page TSConfig at all.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can simply open each content element and unset the value in the **Transl.Orig:** field. This way translations are disconnected from their base.

Keep in mind that mixed translations (translated and copied) are not supported on a single page, thus make sure **all** content elements are disconnected.

If you need to update a large amount of records this is not really feasible. In this case you may need to resort to SQL where you need to change the `l18n_parent` [sic] field:

```
UPDATE tt_content
SET l18n_parent = 0
WHERE pid = <your-pid>
AND sys_language_uid = <your-language-uid>
```

This would detach all content on `<your-pid>` for `<your-language-uid>`; you can remove part or all of these constraints if you want to update content more generally.

Comment: I am aware of this. But this is not practical for a large amount of pages/content elements as I described.

Comment: Could it be done directly in the database? Which tables/fields have to be considered?

Comment: I've added an SQL query with details for this.